# Puppet Environments for different applications

Tags: puppet

Just familiarizing myself with puppet and puppet master. If I have multiple web applications that all use similar (and yet, not quite identical) application stacks, it would seem beneficial to set those up as different environments. Is this a common theme or is there a better / different way to set it up? Surely there isn't a need to setup a separate puppet master for each application?

This is primarily for me to learn puppet but I'd also like to use it for other development projects I do (almost all of which are web development).

Answer (score 1):

That would be a little unusual. Each node can only be in a single environment, so you would be precluding ever having multiple applications served from a single host. I usually use environments for *testing manifests* through dev, test, and production.

Each application would have a different [*profile* class](https://puppetlabs.com/presentations/designing-puppet-rolesprofiles-pattern) which defines how to configure that application. I can then use multiple profiles on a single node.